# Share list of remote git repositories

Tags: git, git-remote

Given this workflow...

1. Clone a third party remote repository (e.g. from github) into my computer.
2. Create commits in my computer.
3. Create a backup repository in my own server (e.g. `git remote add backup me@git.backup-server:my_project`)
4. Regularly push those commits to the backup server.

... one can find that the backup server has no idea where the project was originally cloned from. So in case I lose my local repository and reach the backup server, I have no idea that it originally came from github, and therefore will need to manually search on the Internet for the source in order to ever sync with it again.

Is there any automatic way to deal with this issue? I.e. have the `backup_server` clone automatically receive the github (or wherever) remote URL without having to manually ssh into the server and add the information myself.

What I'd be looking for might resemble `git send_list_of_remotes backup-server`. Or maybe there's a way to version the relevant part of the .git/config file contents. Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone from github on your own server, and then locally clone from your server. Locally, you can easily add github as a separate remote.

And you cannot lose your own server's address, because I assume you don't forget it ;)

```
ssh yourserver
git clone github.com/user/repo
logout
git clone yourserver/repo
cd repo
git remote add github github.com/user/repo
```